How to remove the cookies from the requests to WebSocket?
I'm working with a basic WebSocket implementation:
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://dummy.com");

In Chrome, the cookies are automatically sent when connecting to the socket.
Is there a way to prevent cookies from being sent? I want to completely omit the cookies.
I tried the following:
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://dummy.com", {
   headers: {
      "Set-Cookie":""
   }
});

However, WebSocket only accepts protocols as the second parameter, so this doesn't work.
I'm using React.js—are there any alternative libraries that can help with this?
